# MARIE simulator: multiplication of two numbers using addition

Tags: marie

**multiplication of two numbers 6 and 3 by, repeatedly addition of 3 six times,using a loop that will add 3 six times and store the result into accumulator.**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: it's a dump of a homework assignment, that shows ZERO effort from the OP.

Answer (score 2):

```
INPUT
STORE x
INPUT
STORE y
loop, LOAD x
ADD multiply
STORE multiply
LOAD y
SUBT one
STORE y
SKIPCOND 400
JUMP loop
LOAD multiply
OUTPUT
HALT
x, Dec 0
y, Dec 0
one, Dec 1
multiply, Dec 0
```